# Modify HttpServletRequest after UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlet-filters

I want to remove **password** parameter from the request after Spring authenticates user with **oauth/token** endpoint. The goal is to modify the request before it gets logged by Tomcat's **AccessLogValve** so that the password does not append there.

Adding custom filter to **web.xml** does not help as the password is removed before the authentication.

Is that possible with spring security filters or some other means?

Note: tomcat configuration can not be changed.

Comment: does your tomcat configuration includes POST body logging too? if not, you can try to change your authentication endpoint to a POST url, so the contents of the payload would not be logged.

Comment: The problem is we allow GET with query string parameters.

Comment: The valve already logs the request before it reaches the filters... So trying to modify it in a filter or your application in general is a futile attempt.

Comment: @M. Deinum, not exactly. As a temporary workaround I use a filter which adds a query string duplicate parameter to the request with removed password. AccessLogValve pattern is changed to log the filtered query string instead of original and it works.